# Could Jesus the Nazarene have been buried near the Galilean city of Safed?

Tags: history, christianity

I am an Italian noahide.

I read that the famous Rabbi Isaac Luria, in his "Book of the Reincarnations", writes in chapter 37, within the long list of Jewish Tzadiks:

*"On your way from Safed toward the North to the village of Ein al-Zeitun, passing a carob tree, Yeshu Ha-Notzri is buried there".*

The news particularly interested me, as it attests to a Jewish tradition according to which the burial of Jesus in Jerusalem after his crucifixion, if ever occurred, would have been provisional, as the corpse would have been definitively buried in Galilee.

Is there any other Jewish source on this news reported by Rabbi Luria?

Comment: Please note that whatever mystical methods Rabbi Luria used to identify various graves, a word of mouth tradition was probably not utilized.

Comment: This is not a Jewish question.